# can we use bulk delete in dynamic cursor by this way?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g

can we use Execute immediate for bulk delete like (for cursors)

```
forall i in rowid.FIRST .. rowid.LAST
Execute Immediate 'DELETE table_name '||PARTIION_NAME||'where rowid =rowid(m)';
```

IS there any alternate way to do this job...?
Thanks iN Advance

Comment: What is `PARTITION_NAME`? A constant? a parameter? What is `m` (as in rowid(m)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't realy understand what you're trying to do with the `||PARTIION_NAME||`, but you can do something like this:

```
DECLARE
  type rowid_tab is table of rowid;
  rowids rowid_tab;

  cursor c is select rowid from table_name where <some condition>;
BEGIN
  open c;
  fetch c bulk collect into rowids;
  close c;

  -- here is where the "real thing" starts
  forall i in rowids.first .. rowids.last 
    execute immediate 'delete table_name where rowid = :1' using rowids(i);

  commit;  

END;
```

But I must ask - WHY ?

Comment: why do we use..:1 while deleting?

Comment: It is better to use bind variables in dynamic sql (performance and security)

Comment: while executing the query in your format..it was giving me missing format ORA : 06512

Comment: Can you show us the full code? BTW, I still don't understand why you use dynamic sql, why not just `forall i in rowids.first .. rowids.last delete table_name where rowid = rowids(i)` ?

Comment: hey can we use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  without bind variables

Comment: Maybe there is a way to concatenate `rowids(i)` to the query string, but don't do that, the right way is with the bind variable

Comment: if we have to use bind variable, then we should go for procedures ..right?                                                  or any other alternatives

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you update your question and explain exactly what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: i wanna use bulk delete using dynamic cursor..can we do that without using bind variables or procedures