# Example for insert and delete for dynamic cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g

Usinge `Execute Immediate` for `FORALL`, `BULK` collect in pl/sql blocks:

```
FORALL i in rowid.FIRST ..rowid.LAST
Execute Immediate 'Delete table_name  where rowid '=rowid(i)
```

The above thing will not work. Can anyone give a syntax for `insert` and `delete`?

Comment: Can you include the exact syntax you are using and detail the error you receive?

Comment: hey ryan,  i want to use Execute Immediate in bulk delete. i am searching for it's syantax.can we use Execute Immediate without using bind varaibles

Comment: Execute immediate can't be used in this way.  If you want to delete within a bulk you would do something like:  Where table_name is the name of the table

TYPE delete_list IS TABLE OF table_name.id%TYPE;

(Add to the delete_list the values to be deleted from your table)


FORALL i IN delete_list.first .. delete_list.last
DELETE FROM forall_test
WHERE  id   = delete_list(i);

Comment: possible duplicate of [can we use bulk delete in dynamic cursor by this way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735424/can-we-use-bulk-delete-in-dynamic-cursor-by-this-way)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to achieve this:

```
create table brainoverflow as ( select * from all_objects );

select count(*) from brainoverflow;

declare
  type ri is table of rowid;
  rowids ri;
begin
  select rowid bulk collect into rowids from brainoverflow;
  for i in rowids.first .. rowids.last loop
    execute immediate ('delete brainoverflow where rowid='''||rowids(i)||'''');
  end loop;
end;
/

select count(*) from brainoverflow;
```

Execution in SQL*Plus:

```
oracle@stormwind:~$ sqlplus phil/phil

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Fri May 25 11:37:40 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> create table brainoverflow as ( select * from all_objects );

Table created.

SQL> select count(*) from brainoverflow;

  COUNT(*)
----------
     72440

SQL> declare
  2    type ri is table of rowid;
  3    rowids ri;
  4  begin
  5    select rowid bulk collect into rowids from brainoverflow;
  6    for i in rowids.first .. rowids.last loop
  7      execute immediate ('delete brainoverflow where rowid='''||rowids(i)||'''');
  8    end loop;
  9  end;
 10  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select count(*) from brainoverflow;

  COUNT(*)
----------
     0

SQL>
```

Comment: Would the execute immediate delete staement be slower than a Bulk Delete?

Comment: Of course. You're executing N statements instead of a single statement. I was only answering the question :)

Comment: the above resulted in ORA:06550

Comment: It works for me. Remember that the above is a test case (paste it all into SQL*Plus to see). The PL/SQL part that you need for your code is between the declare .. end; part. What was the exact error message?

Comment: ORA-06550 is the generic error that tells where the error is located in your source code.  It doesn't tell what the caused the error.  Look again - there's more than one message there...